# Gap on left hand side of UICollectionViewFlowLayout

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I am using a UICollectionViewFlowLayout for displaying a grid view and this is how i'm seeing it.

[image: The image for my layout Looks like this]

The problem is with the gap on the left hand side. I am a little new to using a UICollectionViewFlowLayout so am not able to figure out how to get rid of that gap over there.

Please help

Comment: Hey. If you're using Autolayout, the problem might be with margins. Check the Leading constraint for your `UICollectionView`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reduce the space on the left you can set the `sectionInset` property on your `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`

```
flowLayout.sectionInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 50.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 50.0, right: 0.0)
```

Alternatively you can implement this method:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 50.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 50.0, right: 0.0)
   }
```

> If the delegate object does not implement the
>   collectionView:layout:insetForSectionAtIndex: method, the flow layout
>   uses the value in this property to set the margins for each section.

Source: [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewFlowLayout_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UICollectionViewFlowLayout/sectionInset)

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
 - (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
  return UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 5, 5, 5); //desired values
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

My first guess would be to check the `sectionInsets`. You can set them either directly on the flow layout:

```
flowLayout.sectionInsets = UIEdgeInsets(...)
```

or through the ~UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` method:

```
optional func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
    insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {

}
```

[Flow Layout Delegate Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout/collectionView:layout:insetForSectionAtIndex:)

[Flow Layout Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewFlowLayout_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UICollectionViewFlowLayout/sectionInset)